# Mathematical formula for inverse distance in a range

Tags: math, distance, formula

I often run into this problem but I'm not sure I've nailed down the best way to formulate it. I assume it requires a reciprocal...

Basically, if x is 0, y should be maxY, and if x is 200 (or some maxX), y should be minY. So what is the correct general formula to calculate y if given x?

I am working in objective-c but the question is mathematical.

Comment: Can you give few more examples...

Comment: Do you want a linear relationship or something else? There are infinitely many functions that do what you are asking - being more precise would help get the answer you are looking for!

Comment: Linear is fine, yes. John Atac got it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mathematically, that would be this:

```
y = minY + (maxX - x) / maxX * (maxY - minY)
```

To prevent int being truncated:

```
y = minY + (double)(maxX - x) / maxX * (maxY - minY)
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct formula can found using point-slope form.

```
y - y1 = m(x - x1)

x1 = 0, y1 = maxY
x2 = 200, y2 = minY
m = (x2 - x1) / (y2 - y1) = 200 / (minY - maxY)

y - maxY = 200 / (minY - maxY) * (x - 0)
y = 200 / (minY - maxY) * x + maxY
```